# How to create an alert system for all new/un-merged merge requests to report in a single groups/mail/slack channel?

Tags: gitlab, merge-request

As we usually work on multiple repositories , we list the pending merge-requests for a single repository(current repo) in github/gitlab UI.

Is there a way to configure a system , where all pending merge requests for a given number of repositories can be viewed altogether ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use API. For example, if you are using GitLab you can query the API to get a list of open merge requests

```
GET /merge_requests?state=opened
```

You can find more info [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html)

You can build a GitLab pipeline that will query GitLab API for open merge request id or URL for specified project IDs